# python 3 division using mysql response

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to programming python and have come across a problem. I am querying a mysql db which returns a value which i want to use by dividing the response by another number. I have the following code:

```
def sum_perchange_by_sector(dates, num):
   for row, in dates:
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute("select sum(dbdev.perchange) from dbdev inner join symbol

    on dbdev.symbol_id = symbol.id where symbol.sector =
    'Industrials' and dbdev.price_date = %s;",(row))

    sumer=cur.fetchone()[0]
    print(type(sumer))
    print(type(num))
    av=sumer/num
    print(av)
```

when i run the code i get the following output:

```
<class 'NoneType'>
<class 'int'>
av=sumer/num
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

If i comment out the lines:

```
av=sumer/num
print(av)
```

The output shows the types as

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'int'>
```

I don't understand how this type appears to change and why the division does not work?

Comment: are you sure that it's the same data / the same iteration? compare 2 full execution traces, with and without the division and see if a `None` doesn't slip among a lot of `float` (result from your query in the database)

Comment: Please edit to fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really should be impossible for those lines to make a difference. It's much more likely that 'sumer' is something different each time you run it - 'NoneType' would probably correspond to no result being returned from the query.

Comment: You are correct, a debug shows the first iteration returns no result and the program dies. If i remove that first date everything works as expected. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.